# Transform range-based for normal loop

Tags: c++, c++03

```
for (const auto & rRec : m_map_handshake)
    {
        if (rRec.second->GetHostName() == inet_ntoa(c_rSockAddr.sin_addr))
        {
                return true;
        }
    }
```

I have code like this, but range-based for loop won't work on old gcc compiler.

Is there any way to work aroung this? I am not an expert on C++

Comment: I would suggest `std::find_if`, but without lambda, not that fine...

Comment: Please show us a minimal reproducible example that does not work for you.

Comment: Actually, range-based for loops use iterators under the hood. The [solution provided by _@Wander3r_](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60147660/11455384) is what you are looking for ;)

Answer (score 3):

You can use a normal `for` loop. Looks like it's `std::map`. Use iterator to traverse the elements and match the condition.

```
for(const <map-type>::iterator it = m_map_handshake.begin(); it != m_map_handshake.end();++it){
        if (it->second->GetHostName() == inet_ntoa(c_rSockAddr.sin_addr))
        {
                return true;
        }
}
```

Here `<map-type>` will be the type of `m_map_handshake`.

Comment: ok, but why does the range loop not work? How is this any different?

Comment: @mfnx range based for loop came since C++ 11, as OP mentioned old gcc compiler, possibly it's not supporting C++ 11.

Comment: oh ok, my bad, sorry for the noise